# message after insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

i have a simple input form,  want to include a thank you message after a user inserts a data. my `OnInserting="SqlDataSource1_Inserted"` method is not working. i'm new to programming so no judgment :/

```
error message:
CS0123: No overload for 'SqlDataSource1_Inserted' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandEventHandler'

Line 36:     </p>
Line 37:     <p>
Line 38:         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
Line 39:             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TESTConnectionString %>"
```

Markup:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">        
    <p>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" 
            DefaultMode="Insert" CellPadding="4"  
            GridLines="None">
       <Fields>     
           <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="text_test" SortExpression="text_test"  />
           <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True"/>             

       </Fields>
       </asp:DetailsView>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VZConnectionString %>"             
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [test] ([text_test]) VALUES (@text_test)"
            OnInserting="SqlDataSource1_Inserted"    
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TESTConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT text_test FROM test" >
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="text_test" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AffectedRows > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { alert('a message');}</script>");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It'll probably be the OnInserted event that you need, not OnInserting (in your aspx).

This is raised post Insert.

Turbo

Answer (score 1):

Remove curly brackets on your response message as

```
 Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>  alert('a message');</script>");
```

Comment: also try writing script as Response.Write("<script>Javascript:alert('Record Inserted Successfully!!!')</script>"); And other way you can add script to Page's startupscript block as Page.RegisterStartupScript("alertMsg", strScript) ...google for Page.RegisterStartupScript

Answer (score 1):

@MG,

You need to handle **Inserted** event but look at your code, it is **inserting**

```
...
oninserted="SqlDataSource1_Inserted"
..
```